# Dyanmic editing from texbox on the form to textbox with Tinymce 4.3.8

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

PLEASE HELP!!!

I have two textboxes: Textbox1,which is a regular textbox, and Textbox2 w/ tinymce. Like:

```
<input id="Textbox1" type="text" />
<input id="Texbox2" type="text" /> // initialized with TinyMCE
```

I want to be able to type text into Textbox1 and then have it dynamically edit certain portions of given text within Texbox2 that is initialized with tinymce.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       tinymce.init({
           selector: '#Textbox2',
           inline: true
       });

      //Can I do this?
       tinymce.replace("XXX", "YYYY");

   </script>
</head>

<body>

    <!--What  ever is typed in here...-->
    <input id="Textbox1" type="text" />

    <!--...shows up here!-->

    <input id="Texbox2" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing that??

Comment: An `onchange` function to detect changes in the first textbox would work, would it not?

Comment: Well my biggest problem is injecting those changes into tinyMCE.  Trying to figure out the best way to do that. Should I manipulate the DOM? Or is there a plugin for this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hey Henry thanks for your advice it steered me in the right direction and I got my solution!!  Will post later..... Thanks!! :)